# Facing this error : container_linux.go:367: starting container process caused: exec: "python": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, docker, aws-lambda, amazon-sagemaker

So I'm a beginner in docker and containers and I've been getting this error for days now.
I get this error when my lambda function runs a sagemaker processing job.
My core python file resides in an s3 bucket.
My docker image resides in ECR.
But I dont understand why I dont get a similar error when I run the same processing job with a python docker image.
PFB the python docker file that didnt throw any errors.

```sh
FROM python:latest
#installing dependencies
RUN pip3 install argparse
RUN pip3 install boto3
RUN pip3 install numpy
RUN pip3 install scipy
RUN pip3 install pandas
RUN pip3 install scikit-learn
RUN pip3 install matplotlib
```

I only get this error when i run this with a an ubunutu docker image with python3 installed.
PFB the dockerfile which throws the error mentioned.

```sh
FROM ubuntu:20.04

RUN apt-get update -y
RUN apt-get install -y python3
RUN apt-get install -y python3-pip

RUN pip3 install argparse
RUN pip3 install boto3
RUN pip3 install numpy==1.19.1
RUN pip3 install scipy
RUN pip3 install pandas
RUN pip3 install scikit-learn

ENTRYPOINT [ "python3" ]
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed this error by changing the entry point to

**ENTRYPOINT [ "/usr/bin/python3.8"]**

Answer (score 2):

Great question. Trust me, you've already solved 50% of the problem yourself by self-analysis.

You see, when you use an official **Docker Image for **Python****, your Dockerfile is built on a **pre-defined** image; a Python Image in this case (or, just imagine that you're extending that base image with your own custom commands/layers). As it uses the existing Python image, it picks up all the pre-defined environment variables as well.

Whereas when you use an **Ubuntu Docker Image**, even though you're following all the right steps by installing dependencies, every **layer** of the Dockerfile runs in an intermediate container(imagine isolated independent shells), and is unable to set the **$PATH** to the Python bins.

**The Solution :**

Use a deterministic Python base image for your Dockerfile. You can do it by replacing **latest** in your **FROM** layer with a specific version of the Python Image. That's a better practice.

Yet, if you're keen on using an Ubuntu image, just add a Docker layer for **ENV** and mention the Python libs path. Your container will register it for future use once your own Docker image is ready.

You can refer to the official Docker documentation [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/). Search for **ENV**.
If you have more questions, let me know.

Comment: The reason I shifted from python image to ubuntu was because the python image had several critical vulnerabilities when scanned in the ECR repository while the ubuntu had fewer medium CVE's . I was using the python 3.7 slim buster image before this and everything worked fine. But I've been trying all sorts of things  to fix this but I end up with the same error. I went through the documentation that you shared but I didn't understand much. Could you give me an example of the use of ENV variable in a dockerfile? What would the ubuntu dockerfile look like with ENV mentioned?

Comment: Alright. What you can do is try Snyk's Docker Image advisor/scanner, since it can suggest alternative images with fewer vulnerabilities. As far as ENV variables goes, you can follow this link [link](https://yashdevops.medium.com/puzzled-around-arg-env-and-env-9067104051e7) which explains it well. All you need to do is, see where your Python is generally installed, and add it to your path. You can also use RUN to export a path back into your bash shell. Or you can add the expected Python path to your ENTRYPOINT layer, although that is just one step in completely fixing it.

Comment: Thanks for the wonderful insights. I fixed it by changing the entrypoint to ENTRYPOINT [ "/usr/bin/python3.8"]

Comment: @rishabajain445 that's great!

Comment: I have moved my python file inside the docker. FROM ubuntu:20.04

RUN apt-get update -y
RUN apt-get install -y python3
RUN apt-get install -y python3-pip

RUN pip3 install argparse
RUN pip3 install boto3
RUN pip3 install numpy==1.19.1
RUN pip3 install scipy
RUN pip3 install pandas
RUN pip3 install scikit-learn
RUN pip3 install matplotlib
ADD core.py /opt/ml/processing/code/core.py

ENTRYPOINT [ "/usr/bin/python3.8"]  - 

This is my updated dockerfile

Comment: And i've changed the entrypoint inside my lambda function as well. 
app_spec['ContainerEntrypoint'] = ['/usr/bin/python3.8', '/opt/ml/processing/code/core.py']

and this is my path to the script

script_uri = '/opt/ml/processing/code/core.py'

Comment: But i still get this - [ERROR] NameError: name 'entrypoint' is not defined